# Can't load AppCompat ActionBar with the unknown error.Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android

I'm facing this problem even when I tried switching from

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha 3` to

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha 1`.

It works, but after adding some new activities it causes the same problem. I went to Invalidate caches/restart and restart my Android studio but it didn't work...

Please any expert who help me thanks... I'm really in trouble for the last couple of days.

Comment: Can you show us the error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the previous gradle version 27, and change your project gradle config to this. The new alpha-one might cause problems with new activities sometimes.

Just **clean and rebuild after gradle sync.**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

}
```